# codesign_allocate - Not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode

```
sh: line 1:  5257 Segmentation fault: 11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find codesign_allocate 2> /dev/null
codesign_allocate: error: unable to find utility "codesign_allocate", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

But if i run `locate codesign_allocate` it finds it and it's in PATH `echo $PATH | tr : '\n'`

I get it both just calling `codesign_allocate` from the command line and both when I try to code sign a framework from Xcode.

This problem surfaced as soon as I updated Xcode to 7.2 (I even tried uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling, on top as uninstalling the command line tools and reinstalling them).

I looked into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/` and `codesign_allocate` is not there. I downloaded Xcode normally from the AppStore.

Should I simlink the actual `codesign_allocate` from `/usr/bin`?

`xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcode-select", not a developer tool or in PATH`

Same problem for `Xcode-select`...

Comment: _Should I simlink the actual codesign_allocate from /usr/bin?_ What did Apple say when you contacted them about it?

Comment: mm? you mean writing on the forums? I haven't done it yet, will do if no one here figures out what's going on =)

Comment: Forums or regular avenue of support. A symlink might get you going (I don't know either way) but it just feels that the only "right" solution in this case is for Apple to fix whatever got broken and something like a symlink is only temporary at best. (Unless of course it's caused by something you did on your end, but that doesn't seem too likely.)

Comment: I just updated Xcode, nothing else. And sure, I'll see what they have to say about it. Thanks.